# Why can pkg-config not find gsettings-desktop-schemas?

Tags: gnome, pkg-config

The package `gsettings-desktop-schemas` is installed on my system, but `pkg-config` can't find it:

```
$ pkg-config --libs --cflags gsettings-desktop-schemas
Package gsettings-desktop-schemas was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gsettings-desktop-schemas.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'gsettings-desktop-schemas', required by 'virtual:world', not found
```

How can I resolve this? I originally encountered this error while trying to build Metacity.

Answer (score 3):

`pkg-config` needs a `.pc` file for your package somewhere on your system  in order to find the information it needs. I tried `dpkg-query -L gsettings-desktop-schemas` to show me all the files associated with that package, and there wasn't a `.pc` file. For comparison I did the same thing for a package that I knew `pkg-config` worked with, `dpkg-query -L libx11-dev`, and that did have a `.pc` file. So it wasn't a problem with `pkg-config`, it was a problem with my gsettings install.

It occurred to me that every time in the past I'd used `pkg-config`, it was to use a library that I'd installed with `apt` whose name ended with `-dev`, e.g. `libx11-dev`. So I tried `sudo apt install gsettings-desktop-schemas-dev`, and it worked.

Comment: Use [search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=gsettings-desktop-schemas.pc&mode=exactfilename&suite=eoan&arch=any) on https://packages.ubuntu.com to save time .